# Why am I getting a package problem on this Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Compilation error]

I followed a tutorial and this code should supposedly work. I am getting various red x symbols on my package explorer so I guess that is related. Is it because of the JRE I am using or is it something else?

Comment: You code looks simply ok, it's just your project is inside another directory that why it says that you need to specify the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the `module-info.java` from your project explorer.

This is because that file defines that you're using JPMS, and that requires to avoid the use of the default package.

The other option is to move your class to a named package, and therefore you won't need to delete the module-info.java file.

Comment: an explanation why that is so would improve the answer

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I've added a brief explanation, thanks.

Comment: thanks, (despite I doubt OP knows what JPMS is... but easy to google)